# Who on this site decides what is too specific, too broad and too subjective?

Tags: discussion, moderation

I believe they have kept closing or downvoting questions that are in fact very relevant and at the same time I see many questions with lots of answers that... in all honesty, seem like a list of opinions.

Who here decides what are opinions and what are answers?

Whats the difference between the two?

I sense there are some double standards here.

Comment: This should be posted on meta.

Comment: Only VIPs can post on meta I think...

Comment: @DedicatedAnt It may need a certain amount of reputation to post there, but if you stopped creating a new account every time you logged in, you'd probably have collected some by now.

Comment: You need at least 5 reputation to post in meta.

Comment: I upvoted this question so you can now post in meta.

Comment: Which Ant easily has accross all accounts

Comment: @DedicatedAnt worth a read if you're confused about off- and on-topic: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: @DedicatedAnt pay special attention to: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions and maybe discuss what you're sensing here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3060/the-water-cooler

Comment: @DedicatedAnt The fun part is that your original question with a slight edit is only one vote away from re-opening and already has an answer the community deems useful.

Answer (score 7):

This is a [community moderated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160960/what-is-community-moderation-and-what-can-i-do-to-help) site.  This means everyone in the community decides what complies with the [on topic](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help) guidelines as a whole.

As you get rep points and your privileges increase, one of the privileges is to down vote if you think a question is off topic, later you can "flag" a post which is to report it as off topic and that you think it should be closed, providing a reason.  Later still you can review and agree or not agree with existing flags, closing, migrating or leaving them alone.

This question for example, is off-topic because it does not relate to the workplace.  All Stack Exchange sites have a meta equivalent in which you can ask questions related to that specific site.  i.e. this question should really go on meta-workplace.  Hence all your close votes.  And now the migration of the question from the main site to Meta.

Answer (score 3):

As a 'regular' on another stack exchange site that's recently started looking at this one, I do think this site might have some problems around questions like this.

Generally speaking, stack exchange sites are *question and answer* sites rather than forums for discussion and debate, and *good* Q&A sites need objective questions and objective answers. As such, its hard to criticise people for following those guidelines when maintaining the site.

There are a large number of questions here that essentially can be answered with "That's up to your [current/prospective] boss" or "you need legal advice, which we can't give". This is what drives a lot of questions to be closed, I think, as most questions around employment will shade into at least one of those areas.

What's left is  the well qualified opinion. Essentially a professional opinion rather than the rambling thoughts of a random passer-by. This is true even on the IT based sites where you might expect us to deal with facts. A coder's solution to a problem on stack overflow is a professional opinion expressed via code, and that's acceptable. So it is here, if you ask me.

But yes, it's a difficult line to walk, especially on sites that deal with "soft" issues like this one.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, the opinion-basedness of a question is determined by how likely an actionable answer is to come from it. For example,

"Are all project managers jerks?"

Even if one were to have a detailed study, including data from thousands of PM, and proving they are indeed not ALL jerks, there's still nothing to be done with the answer. On the other hand,

"What should I do about my project manager who is making it difficult to do my job?"

Is equally based in opinion, but it prompts advice about what someone can DO.

Answer (score 2):

The question you're asking on the main site involves a lot of speculation, debate, and guessing. What's more, it's not a problem regarding the workplace. Thus, the question isn't a good fit for our site, as questions that encourage discussion and debate aren't really what Stack Exchange is about.

The topic you're asking about is indeed an interesting one. Issues related to jobs becoming obsolete do indeed affect people's lives and is something that society may need to address.  It's a good question, but it's not a good fit for a Stack Exchange site.

Please see [What types of questions should I avoid asking](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) for more details.